# Why to deploy spark with statefulset instead of normal deployment in k8s platform?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, bitnami, kubernetes-statefulset

I've investigated a couple of helm charts for apache spark deployment and found that most of them use statefulset for deployment instead of normal k8s deployment resource.

E.g. the [microsoft/spark](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/microsoft/spark) uses normal deployment while [bitnami/spark](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/spark) prefers statefulset.

I am just wondering is there any specific reason to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Spark is a *stateful* service, those should be deployed as [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

Only *stateless* services should be deployed as [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/). Applications that are *stateless* follow the [Twelve Factor App](https://12factor.net/) principles. Making an app stateless make it much easier to run as a distributed system e.g. multiple instances in Kubernetes. But not everything can be stateless, and StatefulSet is a an option for *stateful* services.

Comment: But there is still some spark helm chart such as microsoft/spark which uses normal deployment. 
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/microsoft/spark